# How to reduce time to loop over an 1 million sets of data using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, large-data

I have nearly 1 million rows of data in 1 column from a csv file. If I plot this 1 million sets of data, it would be sort of a wave-shaped function containing 5 peaks. So the first thing I did is to import this csv file into pandas dataframe. What I want to do is to detect the start time and end time for each wave, which I've already done an algorithm and it does generate the output I want.

However, the main issue now is that it takes almost 2 hours to get the final output I want, which I don't think it should be this long. All I can think of is that I used too many for loops and thus it takes too much time to iterate the data. Below is an example codes. (please note although it's just an example code but it should be clear enough to show the idea of what kind of structure of for loop I use.

```
    for i in range(len(data)-(athreshold)):
        if all(data[i+k] < bthreshold for k in range(0,athreshold)):
            n[i] = 5                
            n[i+(athreshold)] = 5
        else:
            for i in range(len(data)-(athreshold), len(data)):
                if data[i] < bthreshold:
                    n[i] = 5
```

As you can see above, I use a for loop to iterate this 1 million sets of data and not surprisingly it takes a long time to process. So I am wondering is there any more efficient way to deal with this kind of large data set?

```
Edit
```

The data set is much complicated because the values in the peak is up and down within a big range. So I need to go through the data set at least once to sort out the domain time of those peaks I think.. Right now my algorithm is to iterate those data first to make some sort of function transformation. Then loop through the data again to get the start time & end time I want and append them to a new empty list. After I get the start time & end time it will become much easier because the amount of them are small, and the rest steps wouldn't take long for sure. So the most time-consuming part is the two times when I iterate through the data set.

Comment: Add sample data?

Comment: The data is just a large sets of values (eg. power in watts). You can use any values as long as it is like a wave-shaped function.

Comment: If you want to detect the 5 highest values, can't you just sort the data?

Comment: It's actually much more complicated because the values in the peak is up and down within a large range. So I will need to go through the data set at least once to sort out the domain time of those peaks I think..

Comment: You're doing that test `data[i+k] < power_threshold` a lot of times: testing the same data repeatedly as you slide the window over `data`. Have you tried making a `thresholded_data` boolean array of the same length as `data`, populating it once and then using that?

Comment: If you believe the most time-consuming part is the first two times you iterate the dataset, then would it be better to include that here instead of the non-time-consuming part? Also the last inner for loop is suspicious, you are using the same variable as the outer loop, and it doesn't depend on the outer loop. Also, I don't think you need any nested for loop. But I can't be sure unless you show us the whole algorithm. The current snippet doesn't really make sense for me, maybe you can explain more what the `n` array is supposed to represent?

Comment: @justhalf pls see my edited codes above.

Comment: Is this the working code? So if the data is `[1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3]` with `time_threshold=5` and `power_threshold=4`, then `n` will be `[1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1]` and `start_time` will be `[1, 6, 14]` and `end_time` will be `[3, 8]`? What is `n` supposed to mean?

Comment: Yes, my point is that it doesn't seem that the flags were filled correctly.

Comment: This could really do with a minimum data set example and an expected output. It's not clear what you are trying to do. So you have 5 peaks, are you looking for the size of the peaks? The "period" of each peak? Are the peaks regular, in terms of maximum value and period?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to make shifts of your data along another axis. For instance, assuming `data` is a `numpy.array` of shape `(len(data),`)  and

```
shifted_data = []
for shift in range(time_threshold):
    shifted_data.append(data[shift:len(data) - time_threshold + shift])
shifted_data = np.concat(shifted_data, axis=1)
```

Now, each slice `shifted_data[time, :]` corresponds to a slice of your data, so an operation like

```
(shifted_data < power_threshold).prod(axis=1)
```

returns an array of `0` and `1`, where each line is equivalent to the statement

```
all(data[i+k] < power_threshold for k in range(0,time_threshold))
```

and it should be much faster to execute.

Comment: But my codes in the next step is to detect when the 1 starts and when the 0 starts by index, and after that the detected indices should be appended to two other empty lists I create. Could this way also work if I want to do so? (Pls see my edited codes above)

Comment: I didn't go deeper in your problem, to me your code is not very clear (for instance, in the `else` part of the statement you are looping again on the same variable of the outer loop, it is not clear to me the effects this might have). But if you need to analyze a time series in windows of a fixed length, this hack can save you a lot of time (for instance, in the code above you get rid of the second loop, and should speed up things quite a bit)